# How to override docker-compose project name and network name

Tags: docker

Can we override our project and network name inside docker-compose.yml, i.e. without using flag or environment variable?

Comment: What is your understanding of "project name"? The name of the image?

Comment: No, currently it is the `directory name` and can be override by `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`, the first option is too rigid as directory name might change, the other affects all projects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done in with a parameter of the docker-compose call:

```
$> docker-compose -p THISISMYPROJECT_AND_NWK_NAME up -d
```

Unfortunately there is no way to persist it at the moment. 
(see: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745)

That's why I personally prefer adding a bash alias for my projects in ~/.bash_aliases (Debian based Linux) for example:

```
# project PROJECT shortcuts
alias dc_PROJECT_up='docker-compose -p PROJECT up -d'
alias dc_PROJECT_down='docker-compose -p PROJECT down'

# general docker compose shortcuts
alias dc='docker-compose '
alias dc_up='docker-compose up -d'
alias dc_down='docker-compose down'
```

So I can call dc_PROJECT_up to start my project with a project name PROJECT. The network name is PROJECT_default then.

Additionally you can setup additional networks with custom names in the docker-composer.yml like this (v. 2.1):

```
version: '2.1'

...

networks:
  mynwk:
    driver: bridge
    name: mynwk

 ...
```

You can check this with the following command:

```
 $> docker network ls
```

You should get a list of networks including yours and the default one.

Comment: It seems the name parameter does not work anymore with docker compose version 3

Answer (score 14):

you can create an .env file with key=value options such as

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME={project name}
```

you should note that this will only work when the .env file is in the current path

Comment: I have multiple compose overrides for prod/staging/dev - is there a way to define a .env for each?

Comment: it might makes sense to use a separate folder for each environment

Comment: It can get clunky with folders. For example if you use different versions of your app. You use same repo, so it has same name, but container name should be different.